# Scala Slick filter and join

Tags: scala, slick

When performing filter-joins in Slick, what is the difference under the hood between the following two methods?

```
val query = for {
 c <- coffees if c.price < 9.0
 s <- c.supplier -- assuming there is a foreign key
} yield (c.name, s.name)
```

and

```
val query = for {
 (cof, sup) <- coffees.filter(_.price < 9.0) join supplier on(_.supId === _.id)
} yield (cof.name, sup.name)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is an implicit join and the second is an explicit join. Slick generates a `WHERE` clause for the former like: `WHERE c.price < 9 AND c.supId = s.id`. However the latter generates a `JOIN` like `JOIN supplier s ON c.supId = s.id`. You can have a look at [these examples](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/sql-to-slick.html#implicit-inner-joins).

Comment: Well theres my answer. perhaps i should have asked why you would want to do one vs the other..

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) would be an answer to your question.